# Web2py - Auth - Autenticação com MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, auth, web2py

Eu estou tentando utilizar o MongoDB com o Web2py, e para isso eu comecei com a autenticação, mas esta aparecendo uns erros que não estou entendendo.

Num banco de dados relacional, o Web2py cria as tabelas de autenticação, no MongoDB as collections não estão sendo criadas automaticamente.

Abaixo segue o código e o erro quando tento me logar:

db.py

```
db = DAL("mongodb://localhost/primer", check_reserved=["mongodb_nonreserved",],  adapter_args={"safe":False})
from gluon.tools import Auth, Service, PluginManager

auth = Auth(db)
service = Service()
plugins = PluginManager()

auth.settings.remember_me_form = False
auth.settings.actions_disabled=['register','change_password','request_reset_password','retrieve_username','profile']
auth.define_tables(username=True)

from gluon.contrib.login_methods.ldap_auth import ldap_auth
auth.settings.login_methods = [ldap_auth(server='localhost', port='10389', base_dn='ou=people,o=empresa,dc=com,dc=br')]
```

A autenticação é por LDAP, e funciona perfeitamente num banco de dados relacional, que possui a tabela `auth_user`.

Contudo, ao se logar utilizando o MongoDB, esta aparecendo o seguinte erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\Rafa\Desktop\web2py-10-06-2015p4\applications\contrato\controllers/appadmin.py", line 249, in select
>           nrows = db(query, ignore_common_filters=True).count()
>         File "C:\Users\Rafa\Desktop\web2py-10-06-2015p4\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\objects.py", line 2016, in count
>           return db._adapter.count(self.query,distinct)
>         File "C:\Users\Rafa\Desktop\web2py-10-06-2015p4\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\adapters\mongo.py", line 200, in count
>           count=True,snapshot=snapshot)['count'])
>         File "C:\Users\Rafa\Desktop\web2py-10-06-2015p4\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\adapters\mongo.py", line 319, in select
>           sort=mongosort_list, snapshot=snapshot).count()}
>         File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 929, in find
>           return Cursor(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'snapshot'

O database "primer" está criado e só possui 2 collections "posts" e "system.indexes"

Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse erro para conseguir utilizar a autenticação utilizando MongoDB no Web2py?